# Rebuilding DOM-Objects with variables

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, element, variable-assignment

Is it possible to minify a DOM-reference with variable declaration?

For example `document.documentElement`:

```
var d = document;
console.log(d[d + 'Element']); // undefined
console.log(d[d] + 'Element'); // undefinedElement
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the string value of the `document` object is not the string `'document'`, it's something like `'[object HTMLDocument]'` (may vary between browsers).

When you concatentate the string `'Element'` with the `document` object, the object is implicitly converted to a string, and you get a string like `'[object HTMLDocument]Element'`, and `document['[object HTMLDocument]Element']` is undefined.